# c++ template specialization parameter duplication

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Recently I have noticed the following problem with template specializations.

Note if we have the following specialization for `f` and the template parameter name can be a very long type, possibly derived from other templates.

```
template <class T> void f(T t) {}

template <>
void f<VeryLongType>(VeryLongType t)
{
    using T = VeryLongType;
    // ...
}
```

Note this very long type name is duplicated 3 times. Also if `f` returns a value of this type, then another duplication will be introduced (`auto` 
 will be a workaround).

I am wondering if there exists some simplified syntax for this so that no duplications are necessary?

Maybe like the following:

```
template <>
void f<T = VeryLongType>(T t)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: You could just alias the type before the specialization. `using ShorterType = VeryLongType; template <> void f<ShorterType>(ShorterType t) { }`

Comment: But what if I don't want to expose this `ShorterType` outside of f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need to explicitly specify the specialization type, e.g.:

```
template <>
void f(VeryLongType t)
{
    using T = VeryLongType;
    // ...
}
```

is fine. The type alias can be shortened with `decltype(t)` if `VeryLongType` is really very long...

```
using T = decltype(t); // makes it more generic too
```

Comment: Also `auto f(VeryLongType t) -> decltype(t)` if the type needs to be used as a return type.

Comment: But if `VeryLongType` does not occur in the parameter list, then we have to supply types for `<>` and `decltype` won't work. We will still have two duplications, i.e., the `<>` and `using`.

Comment: @Ling True. But if we are to make this generic then there are two options: make the type shorter, why so big? or sacrifice exposing it to the outside world with an alias.

Comment: @DeiDei I agree we should design types with short names. But the `VeryLongType` might come from another template specialization, for instance, one involving traits. In such a case there is no point of introducing a new type alias outside of `f`.

Comment: @List To be honest, templates can often times get notoriously obscure. That's C++. I don't believe there is a better way to shorten this.